# Pixelperfect Upscaled Sprite Background image still shows as smooth/bicubic image in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, sprite, nearest-neighbor

somehow, the upscaled sprite image below doesnt show up as a crisp nearest-beighbour pixelperfect in Internet Explorer 9. In FF works perfectly pixelperfect/crisp.

in IE however, it seems to get bicubic smooth, which I dont want in this case. Any idea what is wrong with this css?

```
.iconbig{ /* upscale the icons sprite images 200% and show them pixelperfect */
    background-image:url(icons.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:200%;
    background-size: 26px auto;
    -moz-background-size: 26px;
    image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor;    /* <<== seems not working !!! */
}
```

Comment: Does `-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic` change anything?

Comment: @atlavis: nothing: same smooth bicubic "blurred" sprite enlargement

Comment: If you set `height:` and `width:` using px units, does it work? Maybe IE needs something more than `height:200%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor only applies to html IMG tag, not to background images. As the MS property only works on stretched images. For a solution I can only think on loading just for IE an alternative css background image, graphically scaled file in nearest neigbor (maybe it is possible for you to use png-8, reducing colors, to save memory. Although png compression already will compress large areas of same color) mode done inside some 2D software.

Answer (score 3):

`-ms-interpolation-mode` was removed from IE9. Apparently Microsoft thinks that we only needed it for `-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic` and that since IE9 always uses the bi-cubicscaling they thought that the property is obsolete and removed it.